# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Unclosed quotation mark after the character string

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Every time I run this code for putting some Student information, when I click to save it, there are always appear messsage in cmd.Executenonquery()..please help of this..

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data


Public Class SI
Dim con As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=Danica-pc; database=SI;user=dandan;pwd=danica;"}
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim query As String

Dim stuid, i As Integer
Dim studentID As Integer
Dim StudentBindingSource As Object
Dim TableAdapterManager As Object

Private Sub StudentBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.StudentBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.SIDataSet)
End Sub

Private Sub Label4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Kasarian.Click

End Sub

Private Sub SI_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SIDataSet.Studentinfo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.StudentinfoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SIDataSet.Studentinfo)

End Sub

Private Sub getData()
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex()
    studentID = i

End Sub
Private Sub dataReload()
    familynem.Clear()
    middlenem.Clear()
    givennem.Clear()
    usename.Clear()
    accpass.Clear()
    confirmpass.Clear()


    Try
        Dim sql As String = "Select * from Studentinfo"
        Dim myAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
        con.Open()
        Dim myDataset As New DataSet()
        myAdapter.Fill(myDataset, "SI")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataset
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "SI"
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub famliynem_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles familynem.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub stat_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles stat.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub HomeToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles HomeToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Home.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub EventsToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EventsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    EventsForm.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub ProductsToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ProductsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Products.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cancel.Click
    Home.Show()
    Me.Close()
    End
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click
    Dim genderval As String
    Dim birthdate As String
    birthdate = bday.Value.ToString()
    If babae.Checked = True Then
        genderval = "Female"
    Else
        genderval = "Male"
    End If
    query = "insert into studentinfo(Lastname,Firstname,middlename,birthdate,gender,username)""values('" & familynem.Text & "','" & givennem.Text & "','" & middlenem.Text & "','" & birthdate & "','" & genderval & "','" & usename.text & "')"
    con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
    *cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()*
    con.Close()
    dataReload()
    user.Show()
    Me.Hide()


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have `)""values` a *double* double quote here, essentially injecting a double quote into the SQL string.

Comment: thanks for answering for my question, so should i remove the one quotation mark?

Answer (score 1):

You have an unwanted `""` in this line:

```
    query = "insert into studentinfo(Lastname,Firstname,middlename,birthdate,gender,username)""values('" & familynem.Text & "','" & givennem.Text & "','" & middlenem.Text & "','" & birthdate & "','" & genderval & "','" & usename.text & "')"
```

Also, I recommend that you look into using SQL parameters to pass the values:

**Edit:** You can use SQL parameters by replacing this code:

```
query = "insert into studentinfo(Lastname,Firstname,middlename,birthdate,gender,username)""values('" & familynem.Text & "','" & givennem.Text & "','" & middlenem.Text & "','" & birthdate & "','" & genderval & "','" & usename.text & "')"
con.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
*cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()*
con.Close()
```

with:

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING")
    Dim query = "INSERT INTO studentinfo(Lastname,Firstname,middlename,birthdate,gender,username) VALUES(@familynem, @givennem, @middlenem, @birthdate, @genderval, @usename)"
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@familynem", familynem.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@givennem", givennem.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlenem", middlenem.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", birthdate)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genderval", genderval.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usename", usename.Text)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

The `Using` constructs take care of calling `.Dispose()` for you, and you should not have connections hanging around. SQL parameters help prevent SQL injection attacks, and stop the query from breaking if you have a name like O'Reilly, where the apostrophe would be a problem.

Comment: @user3428268 Replace the `""` with a space.